# Are there any security issue on enabling IOMMU virtualization?

Tags: security

I'm using AMD opteron with Tyan motherboard, on a Windows server 2003, and there's some unknown or unsafe programs running inside a Virtualbox guest.

I initially turned iommu virtualization on inside Bios because I thought it would improve performance, but I just read in wikipedia that function allow guest to directly operate physical devices, and I don't actually need it.

So does it make a security hole that I enable the iommu virtualization? Do I actually have the chance got my host system, or even hardware hacked? Assuming it's full of the worst programs/viruses inside the guest OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IOMMU also allows operating systems to eliminate bounce buffers needed to allow themselves to communicate with peripheral devices whose memory address spaces are smaller than the operating system's memory address space, by using memory address translation. At the same time, an IOMMU also allows operating systems and hypervisors to **PREVENT buggy or malicious hardware from compromising memory security.**

Check this resource : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#AMD_virtualization_.28AMD-V.29

As my opinion about virtualization I can say that you can imagine it like a host or physical PC but it's working in virtual enviroment. Also if sharing feature is enabled and you can reach your physical resource from the virtual enviroment it can harm all ur system include other virtual PCs

Comment: I think you mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#I.2FO_MMU_virtualization_.28AMD-Vi_and_Intel_VT-d.29 , right? I read it already, and I'm scared of "An input/output memory management unit (IOMMU) allows guest virtual machines to directly use peripheral devices"

Comment: I also found this that suggest enabling IOMMU is actually better security than disabled: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMA_attack#Mitigations